# React Typescript access enum value with variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pw1u4l?file=index.tsx)

Its a super simple react app with typescript where I am simply displaying values from an enum

The enum is

```
export enum Colors {
    colorOne = 'red',
    colorTwo = 'blue',
    colorThree = 'green',
    colorFour = 'yellow',
    colorfive = 'brown',
}
```

I can access the color like

```
<p>
    {Colors.colorOne}
</p>
```

but if I try to access the value with a variable it doesn't work

```
const secondColor = 'colorTwo'

<p>
    {Colors.secondColor}
</p>
```

This code it obviously pseudo but I'm basically trying to access the value in a enum by passing a variable

Is it possible to do this with an enum

Comment: Colors[secondColor], typescript enum is basically an object

Answer (score 0):

you put it in the variable first

```
const secondColor = Colors[secondColor]
```

then call the variable

```
<p>
    {secondColor}
</p>
```